# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate') while implementing react native navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

wanted to implement react navigation in my expo app but i was getting this error.

[image: This is the error]

here is my code on the first screen and where i use the navigation:

```html
import React from "react";
import { View, Image, Text,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import AppIntroSlider from "react-native-app-intro-slider";
import dynamicStyles from "./styles";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native-appearance";
const WalkthroughScreen = (props) => {
  const appConfig = props.appConfig;
  const appStyles = props.appStyles;
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const styles = dynamicStyles(appStyles, colorScheme);
  const slides = appConfig.onboardingConfig.walkthroughScreens.map(
    (screenSpec, index) => {
      return {
        key: `${index}`,
        text: screenSpec.description,
        title: screenSpec.title,
        image: screenSpec.icon,
        touchableOpacity:screenSpec.touchableOpacity
      };
    }
  );

  const _renderItem = ({ item, dimensions }) => (
    <View style={[styles.container, dimensions]}>
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={item.image}
        size={100}
        color="white"
      />
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{
        props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
      }}><Text>{item.touchableOpacity}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <AppIntroSlider
      data={slides}
      slides={slides}
      renderItem={_renderItem}
      //Handler for the done On last slide
      showSkipButton={false}
      showDoneButton={false}
      showNextButton={false}
    />
  );
};

WalkthroughScreen.propTypes = {
  appStyles: PropTypes.object,
  appConfig: PropTypes.object,
};

export default WalkthroughScreen;
```

this is the navigation screen:

```html
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
// importing screens
import Home from './home';
import GetStarted from './GetStarted';

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    GetStartedScreen: GetStarted,
    HomeScreen: Home    
});
export default createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);
```

and this is in app.js:

```html
import React from 'react'
import Navigator from './stack'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Navigator />
  )
}
```

and this is the getstarted screen in which i am calling the walkthrough screen.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AppearanceProvider, Appearance } from "react-native-appearance";
import WalkthroughScreen from "./screens/WalkthroughScreen/WalkthroughScreen";
import WalkthroughAppConfig from "./WalkthroughAppConfig";
import DynamicAppStyles from "./DynamicAppStyles";

export default function GetStarted({navigation}) {
  const [colorScheme, setColorScheme] = useState(Appearance.getColorScheme());

  useEffect(() => {
    Appearance.addChangeListener(({ colorScheme }) => {
      setColorScheme(colorScheme);
    });
  });

  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
      <WalkthroughScreen
        appConfig={WalkthroughAppConfig}
        appStyles={DynamicAppStyles}
      />
    </AppearanceProvider>
  );
}
```

can someone plz tell me what i did wrong i am a bit new to react native.

Comment: Looks like the `navigation` props is not being passed into your component. What does `console.dir(props, {depth:null})` show?

Comment: Have you added WalkthroughScreen screen on the navigation, as I look here you have not imported and added in this naviagation. please add and try again.

Comment: Hi @VishalPawar i actually had a getstarted screen which had called the walkthroughscreen called i have updated the question.

Comment: @Urmzd this doesnt print anything

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code further, and the `console.dir` you provided indicates to me that you're not forwarding props (which is required, if you want child components to have access to navigation).

You can fix it by spreading whatever props you want to pass.
For example, in your `GetStartedScreen`, try the following:

```js
const walkthroughProps = {navigate}

return (

    // Wrapper Begin
    <WalkthroughScreen 
    // Other props
    {...walkthroughProps}
    />
    // Wrapper End

)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you added that component in GetStarted Screen, that's the catch, you need to pass all the props form GetStartedScreen to WalkthroughScreen (component):

```
export default function GetStarted(props) { //or {props: {navigation}}
  ...

  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
      <WalkthroughScreen
        {...props}
        ... //other props
      />
    </AppearanceProvider>
  );
}
```

now you will get all the props in the WalkthroughScreen